# Glue or soldering?

Tags: soldering, cables, glue

A 13-pin cable glued to a PCB fell off. The PCB is for the LCD screen of a Canon electronic typewriter. The other end of the cable fits into the main board of the machine.

I brought the PCB and cable to 2 repair shops. One said a special glue is needed to establish contact; the other said the glue doesn't matter but the tips of the pins need to be micro soldered.

Can someone weigh in? I'm wondering if there is an easy fix.

[image]

PS: My intent is to pull the LCD screen off the machine to elevate it at eye level. So the LCD PCB can't be adjacent to the main board.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This appears to be a reverse engineering, modification, or repair question. Please be aware that such questions must involve specific troubleshooting steps and demonstrate a good understanding of the underlying design of the device being discussed, so that you can ask specific, focused questions that can be answered concisely. Otherwise, the question is far too broad. More information can be found here: [Is asking how to fix a faulty circuit on topic?](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/2478/11683).

Answer (score 3):

The cable has broken away from the pins originally attached to it; you can see that the pins are still soldered to the PCB.

There is no practical way to repair the existing cable; the pins were attached during the manufacturing process, and there's no way to replicate that by hand. You would have to get a new cable from the OEM.

Your best bet at this point is to replace the flat flex cable entirely, using discrete wires to make the connections between the two boards, one at a time.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a bit confused when you say "two boards". You mean between the new cable and the PCB? Isn't it possible to strip the cable to expose the wires and solder them? I can find 1.25mm-Pitch cables with 12 or 14 pins but not 13.

Comment: No, I'm saying that instead of getting a new flat flex, connect the main board to the LCD board with wires. But if you can get a new flat flex with 14 pins that otherwise matches the existing cable, just trim off the extra pin at each end.

Comment: @JeanB Those cables were never made to be stripped They are more like a flexible circuit board with foil traces than a cable with wire.

Comment: Thanks @DKNguyen.

Comment: @DaveTweed, I'm looking at Connecting the LCD board to the main board. Any pointer on how to do that for the layman?

Comment: @JeanB you might consider the kind of fine wire such as for wirewrapping, which is 0.5 mm external diameter, single-stranded, normally with kynar insulation, and is silver plated and so solders very easily.  As Dave says, this is a much easier way to fix it than trying to find a matching ribbon or connector.

Comment: @DKNguyen if the cable is copper foil (as opposed to say graphite as some are), then it is possible to strip them by scraping away the plastic on one side. Tin them up and it can be re-soldered then glued for mechanical support.

Comment: @TomCarpenter I do not envy the person trying to scrape through nomex

Comment: @DKNguyen not easy, but been there got the t-shirt.

Comment: Thanks. Being a neophyte my question is (much) more basic. If the connecting cable is bypassed, how does one connect the 2 boards? Some link would help.

Comment: @JeanB bypassed in this case means use your own wire

Comment: Right, I get that. But where do the wires go and what does it look like is what I'm wondering.

Comment: @JeanB I don't understand your question. They go where your old cable did.

Comment: @JeanB you need to get 13 thin gauge wires and solder them to the 13 pads in the upper right of the picture you provided. Then solder the other end to the connector at the other end of the ribbon in the same fashion, making sure that the wires line up correctly.

Comment: Thanks @TrivialCase. I understand now what should be done with wires. The other end of the cable slides into a main board plug though. I'm wondering if it wouldn't be possible to solder a plug on the LCD PCB as well and use a FFC between the two plugs which somehow sounds easier to me.

Comment: Yes, it looks like there's plenty of room on the LCD board to use a standard FFC *socket*.

Answer (score 0):

Solder for electrical contact, glue for mechanical support. I think you have bigger problems though like how to strip that cable  (they cannot be stripped) since all the exposed contacts sheared off. Get a new cable. Search FPC/FFC on Mouser or Digikey and READ THE DATASHEET. There are lots of forms of these cables that seemingly look the same and you not all with 13 pins and the same pitch will work here. Don't know how the repair shops did not point that out.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone's saying you can't repair the ribbon cable, but that may not be the case.

If you have enough slack in the cable, you may be able to use an X-acto knife to scrape the enough insulator off the ribbon cable without damaging the conductors to (carefully!) resolder it. I don't know how long the insulator will be able to handle soldering iron temperatures, but it may be worth a shot.

Personally I'd probably follow Dave Tweed's lead and just solder individual wires instead of trying to hunt down the OEM part, since you already know the length.

Comment: I actually managed to scrape the ribbon cable using sandpaper and got the 13 pins exposed. What would be the easiest way to solder them on the board? Perhaps using solder paste?

Comment: @JeanB I would use a low-wattage soldering iron so you don't melt the ribbon plastic or destroy the foil wire. Some kind of solder paste or flux would definitely help. When I solder things Iike this, I usually tape it in place, and then solder the end wires or pins to tack the part in place so it's perfectly lined up with the pads. Then I just solder the rest and carefully remove the tape.

Comment: Thanks @schadjo. It looks like a job for a professional. It's too bad there is no substitute for FFC soldering. One would think some conductive paste could do the job.

Comment: Perhaps you could solder individual thin wires...